# AttributeError: 'ClassName' object has no attribute 'driver' on Appium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-appium

I am using this body(desired_caps are set properly in config file)
Whatever I do I receive 'AttributeError: 'ClassName' object has no attribute 'driver'' or similar errors - no find_element_by_xpath attribute or whatever.
Do you have any suggestions? I am doing in the same way as in lectures, maybe anything related to appium + python setups?

```
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
import time
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()
from config import desired_caps
# self = webdriver
# self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)


class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_testcase1(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

    def test_credentials(self):
        email = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("proper Xpath")
        email.send_keys("Test")

        save = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log In")
        save.click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(BaseTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3).run(suite)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make your driver in a function named `setUp()`. The unit test suite executes kinda like this.

```
setUp()
run test_testcase1()
tearDown()

setUp()
run test_credentials()
teardown()

...etc...
```

if driver `driver` is not made in `setup()` the other tests will not know about it.  Unless you make `driver` in every single test. Same goes for any other test variables you'd need.

This way each test is independent of each other, and each test gets a fresh start.